Why don't STL containers have methods for general funcitons?
I understand that there are general functions on iterators that accomplish everything you would want to do, such as std::find, std::count etc. but why don't the standard containers such as std::vector and std::array have some abstraction over them for convenience? For example, if you have a std::vector with a longer name you have to write
std::find(nameOfLongNamedStdVector.begin(), nameOfLongNamedStdVector.end(), ...);

when we could have something like
nameOfLongNameStdVector.find(...);

I have seen the argument that there is no reason to reimplement the function since std::find will do the job, but its implementation could use std::find and simply act as a wrapper for convenience. Moreover, there are containers such as std::map which has a contains method that std::vector would also benefit from. Instead, if you simply want to see if a value is in a vector you have to use std::find, then compare it with the end operator, which is really clunky.
I know that specialized methods exist where they improve the performance, but why not add them everywhere for uniformity, convenience, cleanliness and readability?

Of course, if you only use the begin() and end() iterators as parameters to these functions, it looks like the form you are proposing just covers everything it needs. However, you'd be blocked doing anything fancy like iter = std::partition(somevector;begin(), somevector;end(), [...]); std::find(somevector;begin(), iter, [...]); That sort of things can have a great impact on execution time.

Design choice, separation of concerns. Separate algorithms from containers, so algorithms can work on all kinds of things (with iterators). I think this design choice makes perfect sense since any good library developer knows to seperate core functionality from utility functions (or algorithms). Convenience functions have a habit to grow over time and become unwieldy and unmaintainable.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/contains

Because Monolithic Classes Are Evil. The whole point of OOP is to decouple things, so a lot of people consider doing things like that to be anathema.

"uniformity, convenience, cleanliness and readability?" - I'd argue that's what the separation of algorithms and containers provide. If you had a vector<>::find(...), what should it return? An address? An index? And what should it return if the element is not found?

You still have the option to use the std::find funciton for more complex use cases, but it is very common to use it over the whole container. It doesn's have to be one or the other. Also, you might be able to use std::ranges for that sort of thing as well

It should probably still return an iterator, or what is most commonly necessary, maybe a value reference

I would guess (hence not a proper answer) that it has to do with the lack of extension mechanic like in C# where you can write a standalone func(arg1, arg2, arg3) that is called with arg1.func(arg2, arg3). With your suggestion, every other (non-STL) container would have to implement all these methods and every new algorithm would require to modify all containers, both STL and third-party ones for this system to work properly with templates and such.

The modern way of doing this is std::ranges::find(nameOfLongNamedStdVector, value);. The vector name is not repeated.

You can easily write such helper functions/classes/template functions/template classes yourself.

None of the encapsulation-like concerns (separate algorithms from containers) actually address the question which is one of syntax. Extension methods, type classes, etc. allow one to write nameOfLongNamedStdVector.find without find being a private member function separate from other finds. The committee however rejected UFCS.

Some of the predecessors of the STL did have containers like this. They lead to a number of problems.

Extensibility tends to be quite poor. No matter that they include, people eventually need things they didn't include.

Adding those on afterward creates a mish-mash of member functions and STL-like algorithms.


Many operations produce collection-like results, so you end up with a confusing set of associated class (for example, see std::valarray with its associated slice, gslice, slice_array, gslice_array, mask_array, indirect_array, and probably at least a couple others I've forgotten).

At the same time, quite a few others have felt (roughly) the same pain you have at using foo.begin() and foo.end() all the time, among other things.
The solution they've (well, mostly one person--Eric Niebler) come up with is the new C++20 ranges library. So let's extend your example a little bit. Instead of a simple find, you really want to find every element in the input  that's greater than 20. Then you want to square each of those that's greater than 20, and put the results in result.
Doing this with the STL, you might do something like this:
std::vector<int> input { 19, 100, 21, 17, 1};
std::vector<int> intermediate;
std::vector<int> result;

std::copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(intermediate), 
    [](int i) { return i > 20; });

std::transform(intermediate.begin(), intermediate.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(result),
    [](int i) { return i * i; });

I'd certainly prefer that over raw loops, but I'd agree that it's a a bit clumsy. Using the ranges library, it would end up something like this instead (using the definition of input from above):
    auto result = input
        | std::views::filter([](int i) {return i > 20; })
        | std::views::transform([](int i) {return i * i; });

The "pipe"-like syntax reduces verbosity considerably, while keeping containers separate from the operations on them, so you can build up a complete operation out of pieces fairly cleanly.


For a couple examples:

COOL had a vector with member functions for sort, find (named position), merge, and so on.
std::valarray overloads operators so you can do things like a = b + d * d; on arrays. Example Usage




Interesting answer.  "Those who do not study history are doomed to repeat it"

I really like the C++20 ranges, they do solve a lot of the problems I mentioned. I don't know them well enough, but I don't think they are quite as convenient for certain cases as some methods would be, but they really are great for a lot of things

Containers have their own functions if it's necessary. As an example, std::map does have its own find because the generic template just iterates over all the elements until it finds the one you're looking for, while the std::map can do a much more efficient find by exploiting its internal tree structure.
Find over a vector is inefficient and not something that's specific to the vector datastructure -- there is no smart way to find something in a vector, so the vector doesn't offer it.
You can see this line of thought in other areas too. Like the std::vector does have an insert that allows you to insert elements anywhere, but it does not give you a push_front. It does give you a push_back because that's an efficient, native operation for a std::vector.
In fact, if a container gives you something "specific" like the aforementioned push_back on the vector, or the find on a map, you can pretty much assume it's an efficient operation. Not necessarily O(1), but still good enough to warrant making it a part of the API of that particular container.
It also the same thing as with some other question that might get asked: why aren't STL containers all derived from some general "container" interface? Because we have different containers that have different properties and "preferences"; some containers have really good push_front abilities, while others are horrible on that. And for some, "push_front" doesn't really make a whole lot of sense. As such, STL containers tend to follow a naming scheme for their functions, but whether or not a given container has this function is up to them, based on whether it makes sense.

I see what you mean, but there is also the fact that a std::map isn't always faster than a std::vector, especially if you only have a few values, the overhead isn't worth it. In that case, you would use a vector similarly to the map and those methods would be useful. Also, I don't think there is any harm in all containers having the same interface and trusting the developer to know the efficiency of each option. Some of the differences don't even make sense, like std::queue has front() and std::priority_queue has top() (or the other way around), what's the matter with that?

@DanielBarac The harm is exponential cost of development and maintenance, violation of the well known DRY, and multiple other idioms. Separation of algorithms from data structures decreases complexity of the library by at least one logarithm: O(N[A])+O(N[DS]) vs O(N[A]×N[DS]). Same argument holds for the pipe (|) for range adapters vs dot (.) notation.

@DanielBarac the point is that std::map::find is faster than std::find applied to a map, not whether finding in a vector is or isn't faster.

"I don't think there is any harm in all containers having the same interface and trusting the developer to know the efficiency of each option." That falls over when you have templates. You very easily end up with an algorithm that is linear for the container you had in mind writing it, and quadratic (or worse) for some other containers. Good luck communicating that to potential callers.

The current design allows you to write a custom container type in 2010, define members to look like std::vector, and have it work with algorithms written in 2024.
Under the system you suggest it wouldn't work for any algorithm that uses member functions that were added to std::vector in the intervening 5 standards.
You might say "but the algorithm could use the non-member version, that still exists", but then who is using the member one? You've just added another maintenance burden, for no practical benefit.
